# Need to create a php array using a php string which is structured as a javascript array

Tags: php, arrays, string

Alright, my situation is a slightly odd one.

Consider a string in php which has its contents as follows:

```
[ ["BWS - Bondi Junction", "Westfield Shopping Centre, 530 Oxford Street", "Bondi Junction NSW 2022", "(02) 8035 9239", "1", -33.8912952, 151.2515329, "","1557", ["27-04-2015 to 03-05-2015","9:00 AM - 10:00 PM","9:00 AM - 10:00 PM","9:00 AM - 10:00 PM","9:00 AM - 10:00 PM","9:00 AM - 10:00 PM","9:00 AM - 10:00 PM","10:00 AM - 10:00 PM"], ["04-05-2015 to 10-05-2015","9:00 AM - 10:00 PM","9:00 AM - 10:00 PM","9:00 AM - 10:00 PM","9:00 AM - 10:00 PM","9:00 AM - 10:00 PM","9:00 AM - 10:00 PM","10:00 AM - 10:00 PM"]]];
```

Note that the semicolon above is also a part of the string along with the brackets. All of it is inside a php variable of type string. Now, I need to create an actual php array from this **string** which looks like a javascript array (if it were echoed to the browser).

I cannot use javascript in any way so I cannot echo this to the browser and then pass it on to php using request. I have to do it within php itself.

Anyone can think of a clever trick to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, without the `;` semi-colon, its still a valid JSON string, so just load it into `json_decode`, it'll work just fine:

```
$string = rtrim($string, ';'); // trim the semi-colon
$data = json_decode($string, true);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OcQ8c6)

Comment: Thank you! Works! So stupid that I didn't realize this lol. Thanks again!